# Custom skinpack is invisible

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been working on a skinpack, but it doesn't show up in-game:

[image]

```
{
    "geometry": "skinpacks/skins.json",
    "skins": [{
            "localization_name": "Jacketless",
            "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
            "texture": "Jacketless.png",
            "type": "free"
        },
        {
            "localization_name": "Jacket",
            "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.customSlim",
            "texture": "Jacket.png",
            "type": "free"
        } {
            "localization_name": "Halloween1",
            "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.customSlim",
            "texture": "Halloween1.png",
            "type": "free"
        }
    ],
    "serialize_name": "Custom Skins Example",
    "localization_name": "Custom Skins Example"
}



{
    "format_version": 1,
    "header": {
        "name": "The Logan Pack",
        "uuid": "6deb1528-f2c2-11e9-a713-2a2ae2dbcce4",
        "version": [
            1,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "modules": [
        {
            "type": "skin_pack",
            "uuid": "6deb178a-f2c2-11e9-a713-2a2ae2dbcce4",
            "version": [
                1,
                0,
                0
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Moments ago I had a similar problem and got it fixed:

You are missing a "," in your presume skins.json file, here:

```
    {
        "localization_name": "Jacket",
        "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.customSlim",
        "texture": "Jacket.png",
        "type": "free"
    } {
        "localization_name": "Halloween1",
        "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.customSlim",
        "texture": "Halloween1.png",
        "type": "free"
    }
```

As you can see, you are missing a comma between the two.
And just in case you don't see it and are confused, here is a comparison to **the correct way to put it**:

```
       {
            "localization_name": "Jacket",
            "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.customSlim",
            "texture": "Jacket.png",
            "type": "free"
        }, {
            "localization_name": "Halloween1",
            "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.customSlim",
            "texture": "Halloween1.png",
            "type": "free"
        }
```